# Фильтрация объекта по значению ключа из массива и вывод объекта с фильтрами и числом

Tags: javascript, циклы, объекты, фильтры, фильтрация

Имеется код:

```
const contact = [{
name: 'Petr',
surname: 'Petrov',
hobby: ['biologi', 'football']},
{
name: 'Alexyi',
surname: 'Alexeev',
hobby: ['biologi', 'football', 'cars']
}, 
{
name: 'Spiridon',
surname: 'spiridonov',
hobby: ['cars', 'math',"cats"]
},
{
name: 'Ivan',
surname: 'Ivanushkin',
hobby: ['biologi', 'football', 'math']
}];
```

С него нужно получить объект по значениям и количеству совпадений:

```
{
biologi:3,
football:3,
cats:1,
math:2,
cars:1
}
```

Не знаю с какой стороны подойти к hobby т.к это массив.
Думал через arr.filter но не вышло или возможно я не правильно использовал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapReduce:

```js
const contacts = [{
    name: 'Petr',
    surname: 'Petrov',
    hobby: ['biologi', 'football']
  },
  {
    name: 'Alexyi',
    surname: 'Alexeev',
    hobby: ['biologi', 'football', 'cars']
  },
  {
    name: 'Spiridon',
    surname: 'spiridonov',
    hobby: ['cars', 'math', "cats"]
  },
  {
    name: 'Ivan',
    surname: 'Ivanushkin',
    hobby: ['biologi', 'football', 'math']
  }
];

let res = contacts
  .map(c => c.hobby) // Для начала отобразим интересующие нас данные -> [['cat', 'car'], ['car']]
  .reduce((c, hb) => (hb.forEach(h => c[h] ? c[h]++ : c[h] = 1), c), {}) // считаем, сколько чего, проходя по каждому массиву forEach

let res2 = contacts
  .map(a => a.hobby) // Для начала отобразим интересующие нас данные -> [['cat', 'car'], ['car']]
  .reduce((c, l) => c.concat(l), []) // Теперь соберём всё в один масив -> ['cat', 'car', 'car']
  .reduce((c, h) => (c[h] = c[h] ? c[h] + 1 : 1, c), {}) // считаем, сколько чего

console.log(res, res2);
```

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Лихо вы с этим справились) Спасибо огромное)
Мне конечно сложно для понимания понять как все работает) я далеко не так хорош в JS  как вы)
Если не сложно , пожалуйста, можете оставить несколько комментариев что куда и как?)
И я так понимаю это 2 способа решения? Потому как консоль возвращает 2 идентичных объекта

Comment: Да, в первом мне не понравился forEach =)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за разъяснение) Огромное спасибо что уделили время и ответили на мой вопрос.
Теперь буду глубже учить map , reduce  и тернарный оператор